# Unity3D face object where its moving

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, transform

So I did a companion that flies with you and it is going fine with:
`this.transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(transform.position, player.transform.position + offset, speed * Time.deltaTime);`

but now this is where it starts... currently I am using this but I want the object rotate itself where its moving:
`this.transform.LookAt(player, Vector3.up);`

I would really appreciate a answer from you.

Have a great day.

TobiHudi

Comment: @derHugo I believe the issue is the follower is pointing to the direction of the player, not where the follower is moving to. As the follower has some `offset` from the player, using `LookAt` would make it look at the player, not where the object with the additional `offset` would be moving towards. OP can clarify, but that is how I interpreted the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with some vector math. Store the previous location of your companion, then use the new target location to determine a direction vector. The code can look something like:

```
private void Update()
{
    // store our prev location
    Vector3 prevLocation = this.transform.position;
   
    // update the position as you are already doing
    this.transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(transform.position, player.transform.position + offset, speed * Time.deltaTime);
   
    // now calculate our direction using the targetLoc - prevLoc
    // assure to normalize so we have a non scaled vector, which is just a direction
    Vector3 newDir = (this.transform.position - prevLocation).normalized;

    // assign the rotation of our object to the direction we are now moving
    this.transform.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(newDir);
}
```

The above snippet is un-tested but is based around the [`Quaternion.LookRotation`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.LookRotation.html) docs so it should work as intended.

Comment: Thanks! I really appreciate that feedback! (It works... for real though... that you took your time to help me is just amazing)

Comment: @TobiHudi Anytime glad I could help! If this post answers your question you can close the question by accepting the answer by clicking the checkmark to the left of the post. It let's others know the question amhas a working answer.